# Convert PDF file to Hexadecimal format in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to convert a pdf file to hexadecimal using java.

Any quick help will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Same way you'd convert any file to hex. Which is done same way you'd convert any sequence of bytes to hex.

Comment: Hexadecimal (base 16) requires 2 x the file size Base64 (base 64) requires only 4/3 x the file size. (URL safe) Base64 can be done in one statement in java.

Comment: @JoopEggen that's great and all, but tons of formats account for binary sequences to be transmissible in text as hexa, but not as base64. So they may not have a choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick help would look like this

```
static String toHex(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    int value = 0;
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();

    while ((value = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        hex.append(String.format("%02X ", value));


    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

for a sake of simplicity i have skipped few edge cases. but i think this is good start. in reality you have to check whether a  character is convertible to hex and handle all possible exceptions that can be thrown.

main method would look like this.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("sample.pdf");
    String hex = toHex(file);
    System.out.println(hex);

}
```

Comment: I'd love to hear of anything that can't be converted to hex.

Comment: Thanks! It is enough to start on this.

Answer (score 0):

A nice use-case for `ByteBuffer` (though `byte[]` would suffice here):

```
byte[] toHex(Path path) {
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(content.length * 2);
    for (byte b : content) {
        byte[] cc = String.format("%02x", 0xFF & b).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        buf.put(cc);
    }
    return buf.array();
}
```

Speed improvement:

```
    for (byte b : content) {
        int c = (b >> 4) & 0xF;
        int d = b & 0xF;
        buf.put((byte) (c < 10 ? '0' + c : 'a' + c - 10));
        buf.put((byte) (d < 10 ? '0' + d : 'a' + d - 10));
    }
```

This assumes that the files are not huge. (But in that case hexadecimal would make no sense.)